# Does mysql latin1 also support emoji character?

Tags: mysql, emoji

Now because below phenomenon I feel I totally do not understand character set. At first I think only utf8mb4 support Emoji character e.g. .
See below:

```
As of MySQL 5.5.3, the utf8mb4 character set uses a maximum of four bytes per character supports supplemental characters
```

But accidentally I found this phenomenon,see below:

```
mysql> show variables like 'character%';
+--------------------------+---------------------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                                 |
+--------------------------+---------------------------------------+
| character_set_client     | latin1                                |
| character_set_connection | latin1                                |
| character_set_database   | latin1                                |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                                |
| character_set_results    | latin1                                |
| character_set_server     | utf8mb4                               |
| character_set_system     | utf8                                  |
| character_sets_dir       | /opt/mysql/server-5.6/share/charsets/ |
+--------------------------+---------------------------------------+
mysql> show create table t4\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
   Table: t4
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `t4` (
  `data` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
mysql> insert into t4 select '\U+1F600';
mysql> select * from t4;
+------+
| data |
+------+
|      |
+------+
```

Now I'm very confused, it seems latin1 also could  support emoji character. I know it must be an illusion, but I don't know how to clear it?

Comment: I think you saved into and retrieved from the database a string of bytes that is interpreted by the terminal as an Unicode character. Check the output of `SELECT LENGTH(data), CHAR_LENGTH(data) FROM t4` to see what's happening. They should return different values for multi-byte characters and the same value for `latin1`.

Comment: @axiac You're right. The values of length(data) and char_length(data) both are 4. You mean although in mysql interactive interface environment, the character set is latin1, but in fact mysql client used OS default character set(utf8). That is mysql client use utf8 to encode this emoji character to f0 9f 98 80, and then put them into data column. When retreve it mysql client use utf8 to decode it to the correct emoji character.   So if I could conclude that in mysql interactive interface execute set names does not make sense, because it always uses os character.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot store anything other than [iso-8859-1 characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) into an latin1 field without converting it to e.g. base64

It might work, but will fail later at some point. In special having multibyte characters like emoticons.